# what CV_IPP_RUN function in opencv will do?

Tags: opencv3.0

I am using opencv 3.1 version with visual studio 2015.I am trying to extract the c++ code and I found this function while extracting source code for resize function.What is the significance of this?Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5985d71657d766c4a20159651ddd1342d54f816e/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp#L328